# Calculate stock OpeningQuantity, QuantityIn, QuantityOut and ClosingQuantity

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, inventory-management

I have two tables Item and LineItem.

**Items Table**

| ItemId | Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Shampoo | 2 |
| 2 | Soap | 0 |

**LineItems Table**

| LineItemId | ItemId | QuantityIn | QuantityOut | DateCreated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2021-05-04 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2021-05-05 |

Now if I want to return OpeningQuantity, QuantityIn, QuantityOut and CurrentQuantity between 2021-05-01 and 2021-05-04 inclusive using a query it should return like this:

| ItemId | Name | Begining Quantity | QuantityIn | QuantityOut | CurrentQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Shampoo | 0 | 1 |  | 1 |

And if I want to return OpeningQuantity, QuantityIn, QuantityOut and CurrentQuantity between 2021-05-04 and 2021-05-05 inclusive using a query it should return like this:

| ItemId | Name | Begining Quantity | QuantityIn | QuantityOut | CurrentQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Shampoo | 1 | 1 |  | 2 |

```
select
    items.ItemId as id,
    items.name as name,
    (
        select sum(quantityin - quantityout)
        from lineitems
        where
            ItemId = items.ItemId
            and datecreated < '2021-05-04'
    ) as beginning,
    (
        select sum(quantityin)
        from lineitems
        where
            ItemId = items.ItemId
            and datecreated >= '2021-05-04'
            and datecreated <= '2021-05-04'
    ) as quantity_in,
    (
        select sum(quantityout)
        from lineitems
        where
            ItemId = items.ItemId
            and datecreated >= '2021-05-04'
            and datecreated <= '2021-05-04'
    ) as quantity_out,
    (
        (
            select sum(quantityin - quantityout)
            from lineitems
            where
                ItemId = items.ItemId
                and datecreated < '2021-05-04'
        ) + sum(lineitems.QuantityIn - lineitems.QuantityOut)
    ) as closing_quantity
from
    items
    inner join LineItems as lineitems on items.itemid = LineItems.itemid
where
    lineitems.DateCreated >= '2021-05-04'
    and lineitems.DateCreated <= '2021-05-04'
group by
    items.name,
    items.ItemId
```

I have tried this query which extract each column data using subqueries but the closing_quantity is not returning anything and also this query does not seem efficient because for beginning_quantity we have to search entire table from date above until the very first record and sum it up.

Can anyone help me what query should I use or redesign the tables.

Comment: how do you calculate "Begining Quantity"?  what's the formula behind that

Comment: @eshirvana i edited my question please take a look . Basically  i used subquery to sum all QuantityIn-QuantityOut before the starting date.To me this approach is not efficient because it has to go through all records before that date and sum it . Should i create a sperate column for beginning_quantity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly , here is what you want to do :

```
select   
    items.ItemId
    , items.name
    ,coalesce(sum(quantityin-quantityout) filter (where DateCreated <= '2021-05-01'),0)  beginning
    ,sum(quantityin) filter (where DateCreated > '2021-05-01') QuantityIn
    ,sum(quantityout) filter (where DateCreated > '2021-05-01') QuantityOut
    ,sum(quantityin - quantityout)  CurrentQuantity
from items
inner join LineItems 
    on items.itemid = LineItems.itemid
where lineitems.DateCreated <= '2021-05-04'
group by
    items.name,items.ItemId;
```

I wrote in postgresql syntax , here is standard sql syntax:

```
select   
    items.ItemId
    , items.name
    ,sum(case when DateCreated <='2021-05-01' then quantityin-quantityout else 0 end) beginning
    ,sum(case when DateCreated > '2021-05-01' then quantityin else 0 end) QuantityIn
    ,sum(case when DateCreated > '2021-05-01' then quantityout else 0 end) QuantityOut
    ,sum(quantityin - quantityout)  CurrentQuantity
from items
inner join LineItems 
    on items.itemid = LineItems.itemid
where lineitems.DateCreated <= '2021-05-04'
group by
    items.name,items.ItemId;
```

Comment: Thank you @eshirvana ,the query is working fine . it is showing what is expected but  what i am looking for is an efficient way to show this report . The lineitems table size can contain alot of data and  subqueries which is  summing up beginning quantity from start_date till the first record of the table can be very slow in terms of performance to generate such report . should i add beginning_quantity ,closing_quantity as columns in the table and seed them accordingly. Adding them as columns causes alot of rows to be  edited,causing another performance issue.I hope you understood my problem.

Comment: The second standard sql solution is more efficient then first one  . It gives 63 ms execution time for 500k records in a table . While the first one gives 500ms execution time .I am testing, is this database design and query scalable or i need to redesign and think some other way ? Please help me eshirvana .